# Injection of controller in winform

Tags: c#, winforms, dependency-injection

I was wondering is it possible to apply IOС(injection of controller) into desktop application in winform.I read about applying it into  for ASP.NET. How to apply injection of controller or dependency of injection into winform ??
for more information applying dependency injection of using in ASP.NET is here
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking for - guesswork is needed to make an educated assumption.  Please explain clearly what you want to achieve, and include any code that will demonstrate what you mean.  Also, read **[ask]**.

Comment: Do you understand me MIster now.Thank you for help as well

Comment: Your update just added a link, which is not how you ask a clear question.  I don't know of IOF but I'm assuming you mean IOC, which is Inversion of Control, not Injection of Controller.  Do you see why your question is unclear? 
 Please read the link I gave you - it should help you fix your post.

Comment: How to apply injection of controller or dependency of injection into winform ??

Comment: I can't help you if you don't read my comments and respond accordingly.  Just repeating yourself will not change that.  I suggest you start with a simple internet search for "c# inversion of control" or "c# dependency injection". 
 Good luck with your issue :)

Comment: @Jahongir Sabirov, use "Ninjct" its better for dependency injection in winforms

Comment: Thank you for advice  @ershoaib

Comment: IOC (not IOF) is usually expanded out as *inversion of control* and it's often paired with DI (dependency injection). Both of these are *patterns* and neither is tied, specifically to ASP.Net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Dependency injection to work your application need to have "entry point" where you can create required object graph and start your application.

In ASP.NET required dependencies instantiated on every request, consider it as multiple entry points.

Winforms application starts in `Main` method, where you can register required dependencies, instantiate main form and pass it to the `Application.Run`

There are bunch of Dependency Injection frameworks which can be successfully used in Winforms as well.

Comment: which DI you prefer to use ?

Comment: You can start without DI framework, instantiate main form and all required dependencies manually - this will give your better idea of what you actually need. Later when application grow you can start using some DI Framework which will fit your needs.

Comment: application already is big that's why I want to apply into my project

Comment: If application big already, then you need to do some investigation which framework will suit your already existed big application. I know nothing about your particular case - cannot tell your which will be more preferable, so just pick one and play with it.

Comment: which one is easy to play ? suggest me easy one

Comment: Google and pick first one ;) Microsoft have own dependency injection frameworks if you want stick to Microsoft products.